# Call PHP function

Tags: php, function, parameters, arguments, call

I have php `function` by multi parameter. I want to call this `function` with setting only last argument. Simple way is setting other argument *empty*. But it isn't good.

Is any way to call this `function` with setting last argument and without setting other argument?

See this example:

```
function MyFunction($A, $B, $C, $D, $E, $F)
{
    //// Do something
}

//// Simple way
MyFunction("", "", "", "", "", "Value");

//// My example
MyFunction(argument6: "Value")
```

Comment: set default values
`MyFunction($A = null, $B=null, ....)` and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is use array instead of using number of argument, For example your function call should be like this.

```
$params[6] = 'value';
MyFunction($params);
```

For identify  that sixth parameter has set

```
function MyFunction($params){
 If ( isset($params[6]) ) // parameter six has value

 }
```

I hope that it will be a alternate way

Answer (score 1):

In the context of the question, this works.
You can use each array key as a variable like $A, $B, ...
But you have to be careful not to post $args with the old values you have previously set.

```
<?php

$args = array('A'=>'', 'B'=>'', 'C'=>'', 'D'=>'', 'E'=>'', 'F'=>'');
function MyFunction($args)
{
    foreach($args as $key => $value)
        $$key = $value;

    echo $F;    
    //// Do something
}

$args['F'] = 'Value';
Myfunction($args);
```

Comment: It is unsafe to set local variables in this way. Imagine what happens if there are some keys passed like `args`, `key`, `value`, etc., like any of other local variables. Outer code should not suppose any details of the called function

Comment: @MaxZuber You are absolutely right. I tried to state that it's not a safe way but sometimes people have to see something work for learning purposes. That was my main intention :)

Answer (score 0):

Use an array as parameter and use type hinting and empty array as default value in function definition. Provide default values inside the function and override them by user values.

```
function MyFunction(array $args = []) {
  // Provide default values
  $defaults = [
    'A' => 0,
    'B' => 0,
    'C' => 0,
    'D' => 0,
    'E' => 0,
    'F' => 0
  ];
  foreach ($defaults as $key => $val) {
    if (!array_key_exists($key, $args)) {
      $args[$key] = $val;
    }
  }

  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($args);
  echo '</pre>';
}

MyFunction();
MyFunction(['F' => 77]);
```